# Conflict Between Reaching EOF and Using Unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7

My error is that unpack requires a string argument of length 1, but the script will not return such an argument when it reaches the end of the file. How do I still reach the end of the file, while converting binary data to int data, without having that error pop up?

```
ecgSS = []
ecgFB = []

try:
print("Beginning snipping of ECG data from the holter file...")

#Get size of file in bytes
file_size = os.path.getsize(args.filename)

#Read holter file into memory
holter = open(args.filename, 'rb')

ecgCount = 0
while ecgCount <= file_size:
    packetID = struct.unpack('B', holter.read(1))[0]
    packetSS = struct.unpack('H', holter.read(2))[0]
    packetFB = struct.unpack('H', holter.read(2))[0]

    if(packetID == 0):
        ecgCount += 1
        ecgSS.append(packetSS)
        ecgFB.append(packetFB)

#Close the file stream
holter.close()
```

Comment: In each iteration you read 5 bytes, but you (eventually) only increas your counter by 1. Your counter won't ever reach file_size that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that the file has enough data before reading. For each iteration of the while loop, you are reading 5 bytes, so you have to make sure that there are at least 5 bytes before you read. In addition the count must be incremented by 5 after each read.

A simple fix will be to change the loop to

```
while ecgCount < file_size/5:
```

With that fix, you also need to use two counters. One for the number of data in the file and one for the valid data in the file. As I see, you seem to account only for data with `packetID==0` that is a type of validation. You need a different counter for that one. Let say validCount, your program will then look like:

```
ecgSS = []
ecgFB = []

try:
print("Beginning snipping of ECG data from the holter file...")

#Get size of file in bytes
file_size = os.path.getsize(args.filename)

#Read holter file into memory
holter = open(args.filename, 'rb')

ecgCount = 0
validCount = 0
while ecgCount < file_size/5:
    packetID = struct.unpack('B', holter.read(1))[0]
    packetSS = struct.unpack('H', holter.read(2))[0]
    packetFB = struct.unpack('H', holter.read(2))[0]

    ecgCount += 1
    if(packetID == 0):
        validCount += 1
        ecgSS.append(packetSS)
        ecgFB.append(packetFB)

#Close the file stream
holter.close()
```

Comment: I incremented the count by 5 and still got the same error

Comment: I changed the loop and the iteration back to 1 and still got the same error, hmmm. I am not sure what is up.

Comment: @jrs11 I just edited the answer, have a look. I did not test the code because I do not have your data.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. That makes a lot of sense now.